# How to get rid of '�' character on webpage developed with PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, html

I have a file named `data.dat` which stores information as plain text. This is a sample:

```
I hear people giving financial advice all the time. Most of them aren't rich.
```

On the webpage it appears like this:

```
I�hear�people giving financial advice all the time.�Most�of them�aren't�rich.
```

I have added the utf-8 charset meta tag in head like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In Notepad++ I can't see any special characters but just spaces. I opened it in MSWord but those were still spaces. Is their something wrong anywhere with encoding or something else? Let me know If I need to provide any more information. Thanks.

**EDIT** After further inspection I found out the encoding of copy pasted text is ANSI. Is there any reason why it might happen?

Comment: how you are including this data.dat file

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean by Dumb the data hex?

Comment: I get the data using Ajax. The problem happens only when I copy paste the information from a text area.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh, have you added dataType: "text" in $.ajax

Comment: I have. The problem only occurs when I copy paste the same data from a text area.

Comment: Dump - autocomplete - as in extract the data from the file raw and look at it in a a hex editor

Comment: @mplungjan I found the issue the data is being encoded as ANSI. Is there any reason why that might happen?

Comment: Your editor? Some can save Utf or ansi by choice

Comment: I used the editor to convert it from ANSI to utf-8.

Answer (score -2):

Please check if there are spaces between

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

e.g. like

```
<textarea>    </textarea>
```